# Attribute To Secure Web Api

Tags: c#, .net-core, webapi, .net-core-3.1

I am working with a web api where it should have a request key and depending upon it, the api controller will do
specific task. I am using rest client program in vs code and did the following for testing:

```
GET http://localhost:PortNo/WeatherForecast/GetAllTeams
test: "12345678910" //Key
```

So in the controller, I did this to get the key value:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TeamDetails>>> GetAllTeams()
{
    string Token = Request.Headers["test"]; //Getting the key value here
    var teams = _service.GetAllTeams();

    return Ok(teams)
}
```

But I've few things in mind and doing R & D like how can I make the above with an attribute. Say each controller
will have an attribute as follows and make the request invalid if no proper key found:

```
[InvalidToken] //This is the attribute
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TeamDetails>>> GetAllTeams()
{
   var teams = _service.GetAllTeams();

   return Ok(teams)
}
```

I am not sure if this is going to make the api secure and my plan is to valid every http request (In my case, a simple form submission at the moment), so it should say the request is generated from the web api app.

**N.B**: I worked with web api earlier in small sections but now a broader thing to implement, so expecting few suggestions that can help me to guide for better design.

Comment: If you don't want to execute if the key is not valid use [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1). You can response from there itself. Note that you can use it before any middleware so that it get executed first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
```

..

```
public class InvalidToken : Attribute, IActionFilter
    {
        
        public InvalidToken( )
        { 
           
        }

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            var Authorization = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["test"];
             
            if ( Authorization != "12345678910")
            {
                context.ModelState.AddModelError("Authorization", "Authorization failed!");
                return;
            }
            
             
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            //   "OnActionExecuted" 
            
        }

         
    }
```

Startup.cs

```
     services.AddScoped<InvalidToken>();
// add filter to whole api
     services.AddControllers(options =>
                {
                    options.Filters.Add<InvalidToken>();
                });
```

Comment: Do I require to add any package for this in vs code?

Comment: no, it is pure asp.net core

Comment: I got few things messed up - `The type or namespace name 'IActionFilter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`, `The type or namespace name 'ActionExecutingContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`, `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'configuration' of 'InvalidToken.InvalidToken`.

Comment: i add need namespace

Comment: Last one - `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'configuration'`.

Comment: you must add this to startup ,cs . i update code.

Comment: All done. When I put this on the controller `[InvalidToken]`, it throws `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'configuration'`. Anything that I missed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239838/discussion-between-foad-abdollahi-and-user8512043).

Comment: i remove unnecessary Di. please check again. it work fine.